# Django can't recognize view when add transaction.atomic on view function

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

My django project works fine.
But when I add `@transaction.atomic` on a view function in `test_view.py`,e.g.

```py
@transaction.atomic
@csrf_exempt
@required_http_methods
def test_view(request):
```

Django server can't run correctly with Error:

`AttributeError: modyle 'xxx.test_view.test_view has not attribute 'test_view`

Without `@transaction.atomic`, URL can find my view module.
What's the problem?

Comment: are you using class-based views or function-based views?

Comment: I'm using function-base view

Comment: can you share the URL?

Comment: Probably, it will be require_http_methods?

Comment: url is in format: `url(r'^test_view',test_view.test_view,name='test_view)`. At top `from views import test_view`

Comment: Try: `url(r'^test_view',test_view,name='test_view)`